# How to render selectManyCheckbox with elements checked?

Tags: jsf, datatable

How to render selectManyCheckbox in other page with previously selected values `checked`?

Currentry I am using String[] to store the selecteditems, but as I want to retrieve them for edit(add other/remove), I need to show the original list  but the checked elements are the one in my String[] list.

```
    String[] selectedValues= new String[3];
```

This is how I view the list:

```
    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="# 
          {bean.selectedValues}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{bean.orginalValues}"/>
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Or the other static way:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox  value="#{bean.selectedValues}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Option 1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Option 2" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Option 3" />
      </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

**Note**: Showing only selected values will prevent the user from adding more.

I tried to store the checked state inside the object, but how to render it?

```
 public class Choice {
          public String value;
          public boolean isChecked;
    }
```

I.e use this structure in the view, but I dont know how!

```
ArrayList<Choice> listCh;
```

Comment: By adding them in a new list and using that in a `#{bean.listValuesSelected}`

Comment: @kukeltje That will show the selected items only, the unchcked item will never see light! If you have 1,2,3 and the user checked 1&3 the new list wil contains only 1&3, I want to show 2 also but unchecked. Thank you

Comment: Uhhh.... then 'copy' both lists to the  new page or use a `@viewaccessscoped` from DeltaSpike.